# Unable to call child method's form it's parent in Vuejs with event bus

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have parent component with three child component in Vuetify model tabs. Event bus is initiate when model is close.
**Logic just want to empty component arrays when model is closed...**
But not single bus initiated...Solution?

**Code is here!**

Parent Code...

```
methods: 
 {
   dialog()
   {
     bus.$emit('clearchild1');
     bus.$emit('clearchild2');
     bus.$emit('clearchild3');
   }
}
```

Child 1 Code...

```
mounted() 
    {
      bus.$on('clearchild1', () => {
        console.log("clearchild1...data clear successfully....");
      });
    },
```

Child 2 Code...

```
mounted() 
    {
      bus.$on('clearchild2', () => {
        console.log("clearchild2...data clear successfully....");
      });
    },
```

Child 3 Code...

```
mounted() 
    {
      bus.$on('clearchild3', () => {
        console.log("clearchild3...data clear successfully....");
      });
    },
```

Comment: Vue is a data driven framework, using event bus is a bad practice except for some few use case, the interaction between parent and child component should be done using props

Comment: And Could You Explane How to Call Child Method From its Parent.....When ever  Passing Data Or Not...With Out "bus''

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to move the `bus.$on` from `mounted()` hook, to the `created()` hook, this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have declared you're bus,
but this might help,
instead of bus you can directly use this.$root

```
// Child Listener
this.$root.$on('clearchild1', () => {
  console.log("clearchild1...data clear successfully....");
});

// Parent Emitter
this.$root.$emit('clearchild1');
```

make sure you destroy listener in child component

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$root.$off('clearchild1');
}
```